# Filling missing values while colume has non-numeric values in Pandas

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn, missing-data

I want to fill missing values but column has non numeric values so i can not fill using mean and median

**Country**
India
India
USA
NaN
India

so here how can i replace NAN with India because India is maximum Time
I tried with Imputer class but it is not working

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
imputer = Imputer(missing_values = 'NaN', strategy = 'median', axis = 0)
imputer = imputer.fit(train_x[:,0])
train_x[:,0] = imputer.transform(train_x[:,0])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

`df.fillna(df['Country'].mode()[0], inplace=True)`

Answer (score 1):

Using `mode` with `fillna`

```
df=df.fillna(df.mode().iloc[0])
df
  Country
0   India
1   India
2     USA
3   India
4   India
```